# Is it feasible to play a Grung character in the Descent into Avernus adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus, grung

The Grung race has the Water Dependency aspect that requires they spend an hour each day immersed in water.

I don't know much about the *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* campaign but I get the sense there may not be much water in hell.

Could a I reasonably play a Grung character without some sort of homebrew allowance for Water Dependency? Or would a Grung character shrivel up and die of exhaustion pretty quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are a few ways, as long as you carried around something to immerse yourself in

Firstly, you would need to carry around a box/bathtub/container/coffin large enough for you to immerse yourself in. When taking a short of long rest you can then fill it up with some of the below options:

- Using a [Decanter of Endless Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/decanter-of-endless-water)
- Having Cleric or Druid cast the [Create or Destroy Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water) at 1st level

Using the [Decanter of Endless Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/decanter-of-endless-water) you could fill it with water most likely using the *Stream* or *Fountain* options:

> - "Stream" produces 1 gallon of water.
> - "Fountain" produces 5 gallons of water.

How you *acquire* the Decanter is another question though, so you would need to ask your DM if you could reasonably have found/purchased one ahead of time. Since that the campaign apparently starts characters off at level 1, it may be a hard sell.

As Miniman mentioned you could also use [Create or Destroy Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water) which is a 1st level spell available to Clerics and Druids. You can use it to:

> Create up to 10 gallons of clean water within range in an open container.

Comment: And there's no environmental factor (say, the hot air of hell) that would cause water to evaporate rapidly?

Comment: It's always a possibility, I have not read through the Avernus module so I wouldn't be able to attest to that. However if i was your DM, I would not even think about something like that unless it is specifically mentioned in the book, so best to ask your DM. If you can get the Decanter you wouldn't need to worry about evaporation, you could just re-fill your container endlessly.